# Simple PHP Routing doesn't work

Tags: php, routes

Sorry I'm a beginner, so maybe the question is just a small thing.
At the moment I try to implement a simple routing. I found a Tutorial (sorry it's in german: https://steampixel.de/einfaches-und-elegantes-url-routing-mit-php/ )

The problem is: 
If I call www.myproject.at/ I expect that i should see my Template for this path, but I just see the 404 page. 
I can't find my mistake, but I think its an htaccess mistake.

I use apache 2.4 and my vhost is really simple.
I have all myprojects in /var/www
The actual root directory (where my index.php is) is /var/www/PROJECT/www/
so i configured the vhost.

my htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA, L]
```

Config.php

```
private static $registry = Array();

public static function set($key, $value) {
    self::$registry[$key] = $value;
}

public static function get($key) {
    if (array_key_exists($key, self::$registry)) {
        return self::$registry[$key];
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Route.php

```
public static $routes = Array();
public static $routes404 = Array();
public static $path;

public static function init() {
    // cut url
    $parsedUrl = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (isset($parsedUrl['path'])) {
        self::$path = trim($parsedUrl['path'], '/');
    } else {
        self::$path = '';
    }
}

public static function add($expression,$function) {
    array_push(self::$routes,Array(
        'expression' => $expression,
        'function' => $function
    ));
}

public static function add404($function) {
    array_push(self::$routes404,$function);
}

public static function run(){
    $routeFound = FALSE;

    foreach(self::$routes as $route){
        if(Config::get('basepath')) {
            $route['expression'] = '('.Config::get('basepath').')/'.$route['expression'];
        }
        //Add 'find string start' automatically
        $route['expression'] = '^'.$route['expression'];
        //Add 'find string end' automatically
        $route['expression'] = $route['expression'].'$';
        //check match
        if(preg_match('#'.$route['expression'].'#',self::$path,$matches)) {
            //echo $expression;
            array_shift($matches);//Always remove first element. This contains the whole string
            if(Config::get('basepath')) {
                array_shift($matches);//Remove Basepath
            }

            call_user_func_array($route['function'], $matches);
            $route_found = TRUE;
        }
    }

    if($routeFound == FALSE) {
        foreach(self::$routes404 as $route404) {
            call_user_func_array($route404, Array(self::$path));
        }
    }
}
```

Index.php

```
require_once './core/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Autoloader.php';
Twig_Autoloader::register();

$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem('./core/templates');
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader, array(
    'cache' => './cache',
    'auto_reload' => 'true', # If it’s set to false, the templates will be reloaded only if you delete the contents of the cache directory
    ));

// includes for routing
include('core/php/Config.php');
include('core/php/Route.php');

// Config
Config::set('basepath','/');
// init routing
Route::init();

// base Route
Route::add('/', function() use ($twig) {
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('surrounding.html');
    $template->display([]);
});

Route::add404(function($url) use ($twig) {
    //Send 404 Header
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate('404.html');
    $template->display([]);
});



Route::run();
```

Thanks to all!
And sorry for the long post and if its just a stupid question.

Comment: Since you only have one route, have you tried putting an else statement after the `if(preg_match('#'.$route['expression'].'#',self::$path,$matches)) {` that contains a `die('#'.$route['expression'].'#'.' vs '.self::$path)`  to see what you are actually comparing?

Comment: Sorry for the late answer ... a lot of work ...
Thanks for your hint. It was a typing mistake and a mistake in the regexp (i forgot a ? so there aren't matches.
now it works fine :)

thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can not use array_key_exists with arrays like `array(1, 2, 3)`, they only work with arrays like `array(1 => 2, 3 => 4)`. Reason being is if you use it on an array like `array('hello', 'nice', 'crazy', 'lord')` it would return 0, 1, 2, 3 not the actual value. with the other types of arrays it will return the value, I would suggest using in_array for your code to work.

For Example:

```
<?php
  if (in_array($key, self::$registry)) {
    return self::$registry[$key];
  }
  return FALSE;
?>
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are talking about, array_key_exists() always returns a true or false value. An array('hello', 'nice', 'crazy', 'lord') will have numerical keys, and you can check for their existence with array_key_exists like any other key.